For a lens with multiple elements, does the nodal points coincide with the principal points?
(Please note by "nodal point" I am referring to the cardinal points and am by no means referring to the kind of nodal point commonly seen in tilt-shift discussions)
The (object) principal point is commonly defined as
$$v_{\mathrm{H}\mathrm{o}}=\frac{n_\mathrm{L}-n_\mathrm{i}}{n_\mathrm{L} r_2} f_\mathrm{o} t_\mathrm{L}$$
And the (object) nodal point as
$$v_{\mathrm{N}\mathrm{o}}=\left(1 - {n_\mathrm{o}\over n_\mathrm{i}} + \frac{n_\mathrm{L}-n_\mathrm{i}}{n_\mathrm{L} r_2}\right) f_\mathrm{o} t_\mathrm{L}$$
Given the definitions, it can be shown that when \$n_\mathrm{i} = n_\mathrm{o}\$, i.e., the material in front the 1st surface and behind the 2nd surface are the same (such as a lens suspended in air), the nodal points are at the same position as their corresponding principal points.
But this is only for a single thick lens, does this still stand true for a normal photographic lens with multiple elements?

From the course notes of a senior (undergraduate)-level class

In the limit of paraxial optics, any optical system, from a simple lens to a combination of lenses, mirrors and ducts, can be described in terms of six special surfaces, called the cardinal surfaces of the system. In paraxial optics, these surfaces are planes, normal to the optical axis.

A way to describe an optical system is via a ray-transfer matrix (RTM), sometimes called an ABCD matrix, that maps input ray distance (offset from the optical axis), \$y_1\$, and angle, \$\theta_1\$, to output offset and angle, \$y_2\$ and \$\theta_2\$ respectively. The RTMs of each optical interface can be cascaded and multiplied together to produce an overall RTM for the optical system:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}{y_1 \\ \theta_1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A & B\\C& D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_2\\ \theta_2\end{bmatrix}$$
The referenced class notes state that the principal points and nodal points, referenced to the optical system interface(s), are located at:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Cardinal point} & \text{Location} & \text{Special case } (n_1=n_2) \\ 
\hline
   \text{First principal point} & \frac{n_1-n_2D}{n_2C} & \frac{1-D}{C} \\
\hline
   \text{First nodal point} & \frac{1-D}{C} & \frac{1-D}{C} \\
\hline
   \text{Second principal point} & \frac{1-A}{C} & \frac{1-A}{C} \\ 
\hline
   \text{Second nodal point} & \frac{n_1-n_2A}{n_2C} & \frac{1-A}{C} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
So to answer your question, yes, it's still true that the principal and nodal points are in the same location, even for photographic lenses with multiple elements, because the refractive index of the media outside of the lens (optical system) is the same (i.e., air).

EDIT: This answer is confidently incorrect!
Rather than completely rewrite it to make it correct, I'm going to leave it as written, and just sign post it that I now think I'm wrong.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Given the definitions, it can be shown that when \$n_\mathrm{i}=n_\mathrm{o}\$, i.e., the material in front the 1st surface and behind the 2nd surface are the same (such as a lens suspended in air), the nodal points are at the same position as their corresponding principal points.
But this is only for a single thick lens, does this still stand true for a normal photographic lens with multiple elements?

In the general case, no, this doesn't hold. For largely symmetric lenses (such as double-Gauss designs) that are symmetric in both the fore- and aft- lens shapes as well as (inverse) order of refractive indexes, then yes, the nodal points are symmetric around the lens; i.e., its thin-lens "equivalent" representation has roughly symmetric nodal points & planes.
But so many modern lenses aren't symmetric; they have telephoto groups up front, or retrofocal groups in the rear, or have zoom groups, etc. For these lenses, you can't assume the first refractive index equals the last refractive index, nor can you assume there is a relatively symmetric lens element geometry and also symmetric refractive indexes.
And just from that basis alone, where \$n_\text{first} \ne n_\text{last}\$, the nodal points for the equivalent single-element lens will not be the same.
Edit: an even simpler case is a lens consisting of a single non-symmetric element, such as a plano-convex or concavo-convex lens, where the front and rear surface radii (\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, respectively) are not equal. In the general case, the front and rear principal planes are located at:
$$\begin{align}
h_1 &= - \frac{f(n - 1)d}{R_2 n} \\
h_2 &= - \frac{f(n - 1)d}{R_1 n}
\end{align}$$
Note that when \$R_1 \ne R_2\$, then \$h_1 \ne h_2\$.

The refractive index in question is of the medium surrounding the lens; not of the lens elements. And the question was not about the nodal/principle points being symmetrical about the lens... It was rather whether the first nodal point (refraction/angles) and the first principle point/plane (transmission/distance) are always co-located. And I believe they are even in a complex lens design; but I do not feel I know enough to confidently provide an answer.

I should have said I believe they are the same when the refractive index surrounding the optics is negligible (air/vacuum). I think the nodal point can shift away from the principle point/plane when the index is not negligible (e.g. water).

@StevenKersting: The refractive index of both the medium and the lens matter

As you know, a compound lens has two separated nodal points. Although called forward and rear nodal points it may happen that they are crossed over such that the forward nodal point may be behind the rear nodal point. The essence of calling them forward and rear is that an incoming ray aimed at the forward nodal point will exit the lens aimed away from the rear nodal point. The principal planes pass at a right angle through the nodal points. If a ray goes into the lens aiming at a point on the forward principal plane, it will come out of the lens aiming away from the lens at a point on the rear principal plane, the same distance away from the lens axis.

I'm guessing, for the sake of calculating focal length the rear is used? and for the purpose of calculating the 'view frustrum' the forward?

Focal length distance rear nodal to focused image when target object is at infinity. Object distance is measurement front nodal to object. Camera's viewpoint a frame same size as format 1 focal length forward of front nodal.
